# Help to combine motion paths

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am designing a presentation. I want to combine motion paths in PowerPoint. Can anyone suggest me any tips.

Comment: Do you have two existing motion paths that you want to work as a single action or do you want to add an additional motion path to an existing one?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a second motion path, by clicking "Add Animation" while the object with the first animation is selected.

[image: Screenshot of PowerPoint]

It should be in the animation tab.